# Replace for loop with if statements by vectorised function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I'm having some trouble with a for loop that contains to many conditions and runs for ages (due to the size of the data frame). Hence, I would like to replace it with a vectorised function of the apply family. I have a variable of the format month/year and would like to define a year variable, depending on whether the month is smaller or equal to 10 (October), which would be defined as the very year, or larger than 10, which would be the year + 1 (e.g. 09/2001 = 2001, whereas 12/2001 = 2002). The date variable contains some NAs. Below I give a simplified version of my data frame, including the for-loop that I applied. Any hint for a vectorised function would be appreciated.

Example dataset:

```
d <- data.frame("10/2010")
names(d) <- "data"
d$data <- as.character(d$data)
d <- rbind(d, "11/2010","12/2009","08/2008", NA)
```

For-loop:

```
d$ano <- NA
for(i in 1:length(d$data)){
  month <- as.numeric(substring(d$data[i],1,2))
  if(!is.na(d$data[i]) & month <=10){
    d$ano[i] <- substring(d$data[i],4,7)
  }
  if(!is.na(d$data[i]) & month >10){
      d$ano[i] <- as.numeric(substring(d$data[i],4,7))+1
  }
}
```

Comment: `month <- as.numeric(substr(d$data,1,2))` will get you a vector of months, then `d$ano <- as.numeric(substr(d$data,4,7)) + (month>10)`

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick and easy solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this e.g. with `ifelse`:

```
d$ano <- as.numeric(substring(d$data,4,7)) + ifelse(as.numeric(substring(d$data,1,2)) <= 10, 0, 1)
```

or using the fact that TRUE is 1 and FALSE is 0 as in the comment from Andrew Gustar:

```
d$ano <- as.numeric(substring(d$data,4,7)) + (as.numeric(substring(d$data,1,2)) > 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Convert it to class `yearmon` which represents year and month as the year + 0 for Jan, year + 1/12 for Feb, year + 2/12 for Mar and so on.  Then add 2 months, i.e. 2/12, and take the year.

```
library(zoo)

transform(d, ano = as.integer(as.yearmon(data, format = "%m/%Y") + 2/12))
```

giving:

```
     data  ano
1 10/2010 2010
2 11/2010 2011
3 12/2009 2010
4 08/2008 2008
5    <NA>   NA
```

**2)** Alternately, this could also be done in base R with POSIXlt noting that in that case we must add offsets 1900 to the `year` component and 1 to the `mon` component.  In this case add 1 to the year if mon+1 exceeds 10.

```
transform(d, ano = with(as.POSIXlt(paste(data, 1), 
  format = "%m/%Y %d"), year + 1900 + (mon + 1 > 10)))
```

**3)** A different base R solution is to read `data` using `read.table` and manipulate the month and year from that:

```
transform(d, ano = with(read.table(text = data, sep = "/", fill = TRUE), 
  V2 + (V1 > 10)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr`/`tidyr` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  separate(data, c('month', 'year'), '/', convert = T) %>%
  transmute(ano = year + (month > 10)) %>%
  bind_cols(dat, .)

#      data  ano
# 1 10/2010 2010
# 2 11/2010 2011
# 3 12/2009 2010
# 4 08/2008 2008
# 5    <NA>   NA
```

Data:

```
dat <- structure(
  list(data = c("10/2010", "11/2010", "12/2009", "08/2008", NA)),
  row.names = c(NA,-5L),
  class = "data.frame"
  )
```